# Vector graphics library for Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, vector-graphics

Could someone suggest a good library for vector graphics?
Several libraries support drawing shapes, what I need is a library that can save to a vector format.

**edit:**
I must admit I didn't do enough googling before posting.

cl-vectors seems to be maintained, advanced and documented.
vecto seems to be maintained, advanced-enough and documented-enough interface for it

Still I am used to cl libraries not being what they seem, so if anyone has some personal experience, please share

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have very positive experience with vecto, but I used it for generating PNG files (various graphs). It's quite easy to use and user-friendly. But, as far as I know, it can't save to any vector format.

If you want to write to some vector format, [CL-SVG](https://github.com/wmannis/cl-svg) is, probably, the only reasonable choice, but I didn't try it.

Comment: I'll probably give cl-svg a try. I find not being able to save to a vector format somewhat sinful.

Answer (score 8):

Besides CL-SVG, [CL-PDF](http://www.fractalconcept.com/asp/cl-pdf) seems to be another option.

EDIT: another recommendation

I've looked further into the subject, since I'm interested in this myself, and found one library that supports both saving to files (PS, PDF, SVG, and PNG) and drawing on the screen (GTK2 and X11): [cl-cairo2](http://cliki.net/cl-cairo2). It seems really the best choice if you need both and aren't already bound to another windowing library.

Comment: Having a single interface to all vector related tasks is an attractive option.